# I am not able to configure angular-localstorage4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have followed the steps described in the link below:

[angular-localstorage4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-localstorage4)
When I am trying to import WebStorageModule and LocalStorageService from angular-localstorage. I am getting the following error in console although the compilation is successful.Any help is much appreciated.

[image: console error message]

My app.module.ts file looks like the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import {MatSidenav} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
**import {WebStorageModule, LocalStorageService} from 'angular-localstorage';**
@

NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        NavigationComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        ProfileComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        **WebStorageModule**   //That is when the problem appears
      ],
      providers: [//LocalStorageService
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: please don't share just a screenshot of your probelm and also rephrase your question to match https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience @tomichel.Actually I am pretty new to Angular2/4 so I am not quite able to figure out the root cause of the problem and thus I'm not sure exactly what details need to be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was not able to find any working solutions for my problem, I found an alternative which serves the same purpose. 
Instead of using angular-localstorage, I used **angular-async-local-storage** which did the job for me.

```
"angular-async-local-storage": "^3.1.1",
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error b'coz no module is defined for LocalStorageService.Add CDN dependency in `index.html` and add `angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule',....])`.

Also if you want to modify existing configuration of local storage then you can add 'localStorageServiceProvider' inside .config and provide custom configuartion.
[for supporting Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage)

For using this in controller just inject 'localStorageService' `angular.module(myApp).controller('myCtrl', ['localStorageService', ....])`

for setting value you can use `localStorageService.set(key, val);` and for retrieving use `var value = localStorageService.get(key);`

Hope this may helps you

Comment: Thanks for the response @Prasanna. I think you have understood the problem right but what I forgot to mention is that I am using angular 4.Is the dependency that I need to add in index.html is same for angular 4.x as well?

Comment: Concept is same but uses are different. You can refer to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-localstorage4` this one. It works like charm

Answer (score 1):

> We can use `LocalStorageService` and `SessionStorageService` using
>   `ngx-webstorage`.

This `ngx-webstorage` library provides an easy way to use service to manage the web storages (i.e. local and session) from your Angular application.

But i would like to suggest that we can use localStorage and sessionStorage same as we use in javascript, as we know that **Typescript** is a superset of javascript. also using this we don't need to add extra library in our application.

> localStorage

You can store both string and array into location storage.

To store data in localStorage, we use `setItem();`

`localStorage.setItem(key, value);`

and using array we can write it as

```
let key: 'employee'; 
let value: [{'name':'Elon','email':'elon@spaceX.com'}, 
            {'name':'Elon Musk','email':'elon.m@tesla.com'}];
value = JSON.stringify(value);

localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Now, to get stored data from localStorage, we use `getItem();`

```
const item = localStorage.getItem('key');
```

eg.

```
const emp = localStorage.getItem('employee');
```

Also we can remove and clear data from localStorage using,    `localStorage.removeItem('key');` and  `localStorage.clear();` respectively.

Note : In `ngx-webstorage` you will get different functions to store, read, and clear the localStorage and use of decorators.
link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage

Comment: Thanks for the response Amol. I have followed this link to configure localstorage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-localstorage4.Can you please guide me whether there are any dependencies that I need to add in the index.html or in some other files?

Comment: After you install this library, you need to import and add it in your main.module.ts which is your root module. also depend upon ur project structure add references in your project.config file ie. adding dependencies of package in your project.

Comment: Do you mean main.ts ?

Comment: @sen these are config settings which you can do from your project.config. but this will increase size of your project and its third party dependencies. As some third party libraries don't give support, see this note "This project is not maintained. Please consider taking it over." in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-localstorage4 . i suggest you to use minimal third party libraries dependencies in project